# How to read xml file as it is in browser using php?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have created an xml file  using `DOMDocument`. I want to read the xml file as it is in browser. If I do

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('/var/lol/test.xml');
print_r($xml);
```

It displays the parsed object not the xml itself. I want the xml displayed as it is. How do I do this. I have tried `file_get_contents()` too. Doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like below to show xml content as like it is on the web.

```
echo '<p>This is XML string content:</p>';
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("test.xml"));
echo '</pre>';
```

test.xml content is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book>
  <title>This is the title</title>
</book>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following header to display the XML:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo file_get_contents("/path/to/xml/file.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwer, but I've tried that too. It only shows the value of the first tag. Not the xml.